# Can I analyze XCP Variables using my CANalyzer Version 10

Tags: logging, can-bus, capl, canalyzer

I have my a2l file. Is it possible to analyse xcp files in my blf logs using canalyzer version10
connected channels are channel 1(primary CAN) and channel 2(developer CAN)

I tried writing CAPL script with the help of online geeks. But seems channel 3 has to be connected

Comment: When you want to playback a logfile, which has 3 CAN channels, your CANalyzer config should also have 3 CAN channels.